# Oracle - return greater than 32767 from function

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a function in oracle which is creating json_object. I want to return that json_object from function but there is limit of 32767 characters size, is there any work around for this?

Comment: Return a `CLOB` (or `BLOB`)

Comment: Go with `BLOB`. It will be useful for storing it in table as well, as internally `CLOB` uses 2 bytes per character but BLOB doesn't modify unicode bytes.

Comment: @LalitKumarB - Where did you see that thing about what CLOB stores? I believe the experiment in this AskTom article shows just the opposite. (Note a string of 14 characters, two of which are accented and 14 are just ASCII; the char length is 14 and the byte length is 16.) https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:9526465800346614914

Comment: bytes per character depend on the character, could be as many as 4 bytes per char in a varchar2 or clob

Comment: @mathguy I should have mentioned **multibyte characterset** such as `UTF8` or `AL32UTF8`, for which `BLOB` has an advantage over `CLOB` for some languages. Data in CLOB columns is stored in a format that is compatible with `UCS-2`. While, documents in BLOB format are stored as they are. No data conversion occurs during insertion and retrieval. So, it depends on the use case. More about it in documentation https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch6unicode.htm#i1007440 So, for `JSON` in UTF8, BLOB is better.

Comment: @thatjeffsmith Yes, but how much storage it requires, depends on the data type. BLOB stores it as it is, but with CLOB the storage might increase or decrease.

Comment: @LalitKumarB: +1 for recommending the [UCS-2 storage](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch6unicode.htm#i1007440). I'd store it still as CLOB but would compress it. Then you have characters and no double storage...

Comment: Thanks everyone !! Returning it as clob is solving my problem